# Taylor expansion round-off error

Tags: error-estimation

In the [Numerical Recipes](https://www.cec.uchile.cl/cinetica/pcordero/MC_libros/NumericalRecipesinC.pdf) in *section 5.7.- Numerical derivatives* it's introduced de roundoff error of:

$$
f^{\prime}(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$

as (with $h$ an "exact" number):

$$
\tag{1}
e_{r} \sim \epsilon_{f} \mid f(x) / h|
$$

With the fractional accuracy comparable to the machine accuracy $\epsilon_{f} \approx \epsilon_{m}$.

**Question**: Where does the roundoff error expression $(1)$ come from?

**Question**: Let's say we have the third degree Taylor expansion:

$$
f(x+h) \approx f(x)+h f^{\prime}(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^{2} f^{\prime \prime}(x)+\frac{1}{6} h^{3} f^{\prime \prime \prime}(x)
$$

What is the roundoff error of this Taylor expansion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, and let $\bar{g}(x)$ its floating point representation with machine precision denoted by $\mu$. Recall that $\text{fl}(f(x)) = f(x)(1+\delta)$ with $|\delta| \leq \mu$.

We have $$|g(x)- \bar{g}(x)| = |\frac{f(x+h)-f(x) - (f(x+h)(1+\delta) - f(x) (1+\delta)}{h})| \leq \frac{2 \mu}{h}$$ where the last inequality follows from $|\delta| \leq \mu$

---

Notice that the error you'll observe is the following: $|f'(x) - \bar{g}(x)|$ i.e. the difference between the correct result and the representation in finite precision. We can estimate this with a simple trick:

$$|f'(x) - \bar{g}(x)|= |f'(x) - g(x) + g(x) - \bar{g}(x)| \leq C h + \frac{2 \mu}{h}$$ In the last step I used the triangle inequality + the F.D. truncation error (where $C$ of course depends on 2nd derivative of $f$ in the interval ) and the estimate above.
In this way you can also compute the optimal $h$, i.e. $\bar{h} = \sqrt{\frac{2 \mu}{C}}$. As a consequence, you'll observe that for $0<h<\bar{h}$ the roundoff error will dominate and you'll keep loosing accuracy

Comment: Thank you. So, could I do something similar with the third degree Taylor expansion? I really don't know how to do it with those derivatives in the expression...

Comment: The roundoff comes from floating point representation. What you can say is that every time you evaluate your function in your machine, you'll obtain $F(x) (1+\delta)$ instead of plain $F(x)$. Of course, every evaluation of a term in the Taylor expansion will not be exact. However, what you're interested in is the impact of the roundoff on the resulting approximation of $f'(x)$, and hence we splitted the two sources of error here: - the FD approximation error (coming from the Taylor expansion, assuming *exact arithmetic") 
- the error coming from the finite precision of your machine @LongJohn